# Uso de Query SQL com Asp MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework-6

como faço pra executar uma query de SQL com ASP MVC5 + Entity?

Exemplo, preciso usar o "count" em uma tabela chamada "modelos" sou dev php e estou aprendendo agora Asp.net framework mvc 5 e não faço ideia de como fazer isso...

Para criar o MVC usei a opção do próprio entity (criei a model, context) ai ja gerou o controller e as views

Segue codigo do controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TeZ.Models
{
    public class MembersController : Controller
    {
        private MembersContext db = new MembersContext();

        // GET: Members
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.members.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Members/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Member member = db.members.Find(id);
            if (member == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(member);
        }

        // GET: Members/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Members/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "mbMatricula,mbName,mbFunc,mbMail,mbPic,mbPass,mbActive")] Member member)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.members.Add(member);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(member);
        }

        // GET: Members/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Member member = db.members.Find(id);
            if (member == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(member);
        }

        // POST: Members/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "mbMatricula,mbName,mbFunc,mbMail,mbPic,mbPass,mbActive")] Member member)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(member);
        }

        // GET: Members/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Member member = db.members.Find(id);
            if (member == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(member);
        }

        // POST: Members/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Member member = db.members.Find(id);
            db.members.Remove(member);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: se tem o código de algum `Controller`?

Comment: Tenho sim estarei editando e colocando

Comment: `private MembersContext db = new MembersContext();` essa é sua classe ORM correto então seria `db.modelos.count()` ....

Comment: Por mais que o `Enumerable.Count()` resolva, você pode fazer consulta SQL bruta utilizando o .`Database.SqlQuery("SELECT * ...")` caso o exemplo era hipotético e você queira fazer outra consulta.

Comment: Mas então, eu coloco esses dados aonde? No controller antes de retornar a view? E como eu chamo os dados na view? 

Sou bem burro em relação a asp e entity uso muito o Laravel hehe

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, já consegui aqui =) só usar o @Model.Count() dentro da view tks

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar uma resposta com base no que você disse nos comentários.

Primeiramente, para executar um `Count` numa tabela do banco de dados e retornar o seu valor, você pode usar o método `Count` no DbSet que representa a tabela (**`members`** é o DbSet neste caso).

Para que este valor seja "enviado" para uma *view*, você precisa especificar isto na chamada do método `View()`.

```
public class MembersController : Controller
{
    private MembersContext db = new MembersContext();

    public ActionResult Contador()
    {
        var count = db.members.Count();
        return View(count);
    }
}
```